# How many virtual adapters can be configured with netplan on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

I have an ethernet interface on my Ubuntu 20 server machine called `enp65s0f1`. I want to create a number of virtual interfaces each with their own mac address and ip address that piggy back on this interface and get their own IP address from my DHCP server. I'm using the below netplan configuration to accomplish this, however the 8th (and anything after it) virtual device is never created, and there aren't any logs about it's failure in any logs (although i do see logs about it setting up the rest of them).  Is there a limit to the number of virtual devices that you can created with netplan? If so, is it *really* 8? Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong.  Thanks!

```
# This is the network config written by 'home-lab'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:

    enp65s0f1v0:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:57
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: plex
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v1:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:58
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: sabnzbd
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v2:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:59
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: sonarr
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v3:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:60
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: radarr
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v4:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:61
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: minecraft
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v5:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:62
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: sevendaystodie
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v6:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:63
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: portainer
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v7:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:6b:3c:64
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: phpvirtualbox
        send-hostname: true

    enp65s0f1v8:
      macaddress: 52:54:00:1b:3d:00
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        hostname: eco-nds
        send-hostname: true
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or configuring Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but do check their help before posting.